# comma separated string to List<int> in C#

Tags: c#

So I have comma-separated string like "1,5,7", so what's the most simple and native way to convert this string to List int? How can i write own split function by using Typeconverter.Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: String.split().  Then, for each element in the returned array, convert to int and add to the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var list = input.Split(',').Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..but i need to achieve by typeconverter...If there is any possible way available....

Comment: "achieve by typeconverter".. what do you mean? You've asked for a `List<int>`.. I gave you one.

Comment: i have property named as item in List<int> type. In aspx page pass value as "3,4".So i need to write converter for handle this kind of properties in my entire project....

Comment: Put this code into a static class then and call it wherever you need it. Without seeing your code I am unable to hand-hold you through this...

Comment: The lambda expression provided above will do that. You don't need a type converter. Instead, place the provided code in a reusable method. That way it can be used through-out the project. Personally you should be able to just use that lambda in each place you need to do the conversion. If you are running a version of .net under 3.5, you should specify.

Comment: In C# file.                                            [JsonProperty("items")]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Bindable(true)]                
        public List<int> Items
        {
            get { return this.Items; }
            set { this.Items = value; }
        }

Comment: In aspx page    <control ID="data" runat="server" Items="0,1">

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
String SelectedServices= "1,2,3,4,5" 

String[] temp = SelectedServices.Split(',');
Int32[] SelectedServicesList = Array.ConvertAll(temp, int.Parse);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..but i need to achieve by typeconverter...If there is any possible way available....